# How to use free() function for a pointer array?

Tags: arrays, c, point

I've declared a struct and a pointer array by the declared struct.

```
struct Book* Collection[100];
```

Before the code ends I want to free up my memory using free function. free function is called up after printf() at printCollection()

```
void printCollection(struct Book* col, int num) {
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < num; i++) {
        printf("Name: %s Author: %s Page: %d Price: %d\n", col[i].name, col[i].author, col[i].page, col[i].price);
        free(col[i]);
    }
}
```

but I can't even build the program because of a error. Could I get some help?

Comment: what error?show us

Comment: also does `struct Book` contain any pointer members? i mean `name` , `author` etc...

Comment: You cannot free `struct Book`, which is not a pointer. It looks weird that a function named `printCollection` is destroying that is passed, so I think the line `free(col[i]);` should simply be removed.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change `printCollection` to look like this:

```c
void printCollection(struct Book* col[], int num) {
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < num; i++) {
        printf("Name: %s Author: %s Page: %d Price: %d\n",
            col[i]->name, col[i]->author, col[i]->page, col[i]->price);
        free(col[i]);
    }
}
```

Your original function signature only passes one pointer to the function when you need to pass an array of pointers.

Comment: Wouldn't that be the same as `struct Book **col`?? (both are fine, just a bit strange to look at `* col[]`)